# Differential geometry: identify surface

Tags: differential-geometry

In an exercise I solved, we calculated the Gaussian curvature of a regular parametrized surface with given coefficients for the first fundamental form: $F=0$, $E=G=4/(1-u^2-v^2)^2$. One can easily see that the Gaussian curvature is $K=-1$, i.e. a constant negative Gaussian curvature. This is not part of the exercise, but I was wondering what kind of surface might be hiding behind the first fundamental form. In a sense, it is quite similar to the first fundamental form for the stereographic projection (through the north pole), which has $F=0$, $E=G=4/(1+u^2+v^2)^2$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the hyperbolic plane in the unit disk model. It is not a surface that gets its metric from an embedding in $\Bbb R^3$. (Hilbert proved that there can be no complete surface of constant negative curvature in $\Bbb R^3$. If you're curious, you can check that this surface *is* complete.)

Comment: Thanks! Ok, I'll look into it.